# Silex 1.3.5 No request POST parameters

Tags: symfony, http, post, request, silex

Building an app with Silex 1.3.5. Im trying to get a form to submit its POST data but having trouble.

Im not using the Form service at this point for my own reasons so its a normal html form built in twig like such:

```
{% extends "layout.twig" %}
{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ path('customer.createPost') }}?tst=TEST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Customer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

As you can see as a test I have placed a query parameter to the end of the POST URI, and from this next screenshot we can see that there is a query parameter in the Request object but no request parameters in the Request object. I cannot for the life of me figure out why:

[image]

Im using rcontroller providers and have registered the route as such:

```
    $customer->post('/create/new', "customer.controller:createPost")->bind('customer.createPost');
```

And In my controller I am injecting the Request object:

```
public function createPost(Request $request)
{

}
```

Any reason why I wouldnt getting POST data in my request?

Comment: Your input needs a name.

Comment: Now i feel silly! Thankyou very much